# Integrate ngrx into my code

Tags: ngrx

I'm trying to get how to add ngrx into my current project structure.

I've got all concepts around ngrx/reflux. Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out how to rebuild project structure in order to integrate it into my project.

1. Where do I need to add reducers?
2. Where do I need to add states?
3. What about actions?
4. Where should Store be, on a service, injected in each component?
5. Where or when the data should be fetched from server?

Is there any project structure best practice over there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should take a look into `@ngrx/store` documentation : https://github.com/ngrx/store#setup

I've made a small (funny) project to demonstrate how to use :
- `angular`
- `ngrx/store`
- `ngrx/effects`
- [normalized state](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)
- [selectors](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)

You can find it here : https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync

---

To give you some info about how it works :
 - [core.module.ts](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/core/core.module.ts#L32) is were I declare my root reducer
 - [root.reducer.ts](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/shared/state/root.reducer.ts) is were I build the root reducer and [compose it with middlewares](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/shared/state/root.reducer.ts#L25) according to dev/prod env
- For a reducer, I keep every [related part together](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/tree/master/frontend/src/app/shared/state/users) (interface(s) + reducer + effects + selectors)

Then within a component, to access the *store* simply do like [that](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/tree/master/frontend/src/app/shared/state/users) :
**Inject the store :**

```
constructor(private _store$: Store<IStore>) { }
```

**Get data from either**
***a) A selector (ex)***

```
this._pizzasCategories$ = this._store$.let(getCategoriesAndPizzas());
```

**b) Directly from the store (ex)**

```
this._idCurrentUser$ = this
      ._store$
      .select(state => state.users.idCurrentUser);
```

Notice that I didn't `subscribe` which means I'm using in my view the `async` pipe so angular subscribe to the Observable for me.

But of course you can also do it by hand and use subscribe in your ts.

---

***PS:*** I'll be releasing a starter with all that already setup to avoid loosing time with all of that when starting a new project. I'll try to release it this week and I'll update this post as soon as it's done. Maybe it might help you.

**EDIT 12/05/17**
Late but I finally released the starter :) !
https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter

Comment: Thanks! Nevertheless, I don't quite get why do you create a `SharedModule` and a `CoreModule`...?

Comment: I like to keep `AppModule` as clean as possible. By clean I mean don't write in it so it's painless to upgrade with the cli. You could move this `CoreModule` into `AppModule` if it's more clear to you and keep only `AppModule` + `SharedModule`.

Comment: Ok, my comment didn't ask you for that, it seems ok for me. I meant which contents (imports, providers...) do you assign to `CoreModule` and which others on `SharedModule`. I don't know if I've explained so well...

Comment: Ok I get it. I put in `CoreModule` everything that I don't want to share. (Legit right ? ). Which is mostly the modules that I need to import with `forRoot` method.