# Create reducer about user state

Tags: ngrx

I'm trying to apply `reflux/ngrx` on my current front-end project.

I want to take advantage of this in order to change a slight functionality: Change current user related tasks in order to use a single user state.

Current user related tasks: Currently, I'm using an traditional model in order to achieve user login process... `UserService` is able to check user credentials. Once it's been checked I store user information on an `AppService`:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private fb: FormBuilder;
    private form:FormGroup;
    private commty: UsersService;
    private router: Router;
    private appState: AppState;

    private alerts: Array<Object>;

    constructor()
    {
        this.alerts = [];
    }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            user: ['', Validators.required],
            passwd: ['', Validators.minLength(6)]
        });
    }

    public checkPasswd():void {
        this.clearAlerts();
        this.commty.checkPasswd(this.form.value.mail, this.form.value.passwd)
        .subscribe(
            (result: any) => {
                this.appState.user = result;
                this.router.navigate(['/app']);
            },
            (error: any) => {
                this.addAlert(error.message);
            }
        );
    }

    private addAlert(message: string): void {
        this.alerts.push({type: 'danger', msg: message});
    }

    public closeAlert(index): void {
        this.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

    private clearAlerts(): void {
        this.alerts.splice(0, this.alerts.length);
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused about how to move this code in order to use `reflux/ngrx`. I'ce read a bit about this topic, nevertheless I'm not quite able to figure out how to move my code. Up to now, I've created an single `Store` and `User` interfaces:

`store.interface.ts`:

```
export interface IStore {
    user: IUser
    sources: ISourceRedux;
}
```

`user.interfcae.ts`:

```
export interface IUser {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    customer: string;
}
```

The next step I think I need to do is to create reducers. This step is which I don't quite understand how build this code. Up to now

`user.initialstate.ts`:

```
export function initialUserState(): IUser {
    return {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        username: '',
        customer: '',
        sources: []
    };
};
```

`user.reducer.ts`

```
export class User {
  private static reducerName = 'USER_REDUCER';

  public static reducer(user = initialUserState(), {type, payload}: Action) {
    if (typeof User.mapActionsToMethod[type] === 'undefined') {
      return user;
    }

    return User.mapActionsToMethod[type](user, type, payload);
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------

  // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
  private static mapActionsToMethod = {};
}
```

Which reducers I should create in order to:

1. Check credentials.
2. If credentials are right get this user and update User state store.
3. If credentials are wrong inform the process has failed.

Perhaps I'm merging concepts... I need some lights...

**EDIT**

```
public connect(user: string, currentPasswd: string, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<UserDTO> {
        return this.checkPasswdWithHttpInfo(id, currentPasswd, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status >= 500) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else { //if (error.status >= 400) {
                    const body = error.json() || '';
                    const code = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
                    const message = body.message || JSON.stringify(body);
                    return Observable.throw(ApiError.create(code, message));
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is the next question of your "[Integrate ngrx into my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064201/integrate-ngrx-into-my-code)" =).

What you're looking for is : https://github.com/ngrx/effects

The idea behind effects is that an effect let you catch an Action, do side effect (API call or whatever) and you can then dispatch another Action (often success or error).

**Flow example to connect a user :**
 --| [*from component*] Dispatch action `USER_CONNECT`
 --| [from user.effect.ts]
 ----| Catch action `ofType('USER_CONNECT')`
 ----| Do what you need to do (API call for ex)
 ----| When the response comes back :
 ------| If success : Dispatch `USER_CONNECT_SUCCESS`
 ------| If error : Dispatch `USER_CONNECT_ERROR`

Of course when you dispatch either `USER_CONNECT_SUCCESS` or `USER_CONNECT_ERROR` you can pass additional data in the `payload` (for example user information or the error).

Here's a full example :

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersEffects {
  constructor(
    private _actions$: Actions,
    private _store$: Store<IStore>,
    private _userService: UserService,
  ) { }

  @Effect({ dispatch: true }) userConnect$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_CONNECT')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.connect(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((res: Response) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Error while connecting user !');
          }

          const rslt = res.json();
          return { type: 'USER_CONNECT_SUCCESS', payload: rslt };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (environment.debug) {
            console.group();
            console.warn('Error catched in users.effects.ts : ofType(USER_CONNECT)');
            console.error(err);
            console.groupEnd();
          }

          return Observable.of({
            type: 'USER_CONNECT_ERROR',
            payload: { error: err }
          });
        })
    );
}
```

You can take a look into my project [Pizza-Sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync/blob/master/frontend/src/app/shared/state/users/users.effects.ts) were I did something similar (except that I don't catch in case of error and do not dispatch if there's an error).